# How to create a sum function under last piece of column data with flexibility

Tags: vba, excel

```
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("L108").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-106]C:R[-1]C)"
Range("L108").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("L108:N108").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.FillRight
```

need to add a sum function under column L, M, and N with ability to be able to adapt to other spreadsheets where number of rows will change so the sum will not be the same range

Comment: To help you with this it is necessary to know what prompts you to select L108 before inputting a formula.

Comment: in this particular excel sheet 108 was the last cell with contents in it

Answer (score 1):

This will find the bottom value (row 107 from your sample code) and input a SUM formula in the next row (row 108 in your sample) for columns L, M and N.

```
dim lr as long
with worksheets("sheet1")
    lr = .cells(.rows.count, "L").end(xlup).row
    .cells(lr + 1, "L").resize(1, 3).formular1c1 = _
        "=sum(r2c:r" & lr & "c)"
end with
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will insert a formula below the last cell in column **B**:

```
Sub MakeColumnSum()
    Dim kolumn As String, where As Range
    kolumn = "B"
    Set where = Range(kolumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    where.Formula = "=SUM(" & kolumn & "1:" & kolumn & where.Row - 1 & ")"
End Sub
```